# Duplicate row database function

Tags: php, mysql, sql, post, pdo

i try to duplicate a row of my database but my function does not work and not return error php or print error my var dump return only array (size=1)
  'id' => string '11',

my code in my controller:

```
public function duplicateOutil(){
 var_dump($_POST);

   if (isset($_POST["id"])){
    $o = new Outillage($_POST["id"]);
   if (isset($_POST["id_art"])){
    $o->__set("id_art", $_POST["id_art"]);
   }
   if (isset($_POST["num_serie"])){
    $o->__set("num_serie",$_POST["num_serie"]);
   }
   if (isset($_POST["article"])){
    $o->__set("article", $_POST["art"]);
   }
   if (isset($_POST["id_doc"])){
    $o->__set("id_doc", $_POST["id_doc"]);
   }
   if (isset($_POST["document"])){
    $o->__set("document", $_POST["doc"]);
   }
   if (isset($_POST["ilot"])){ 
    $o->__set("ilot", ilot::findAllByName($_POST["ilot"]));
   }
   if (isset($_POST["emplacement"])){
    $o->__set("emplacement", $_POST["emplacement"]);
   }
   if (isset($_POST["liste_tubes"])){
    $o->__set("liste_tubes", $_POST["tube"]);
   }
    $o->insert();
 }else{
     echo('erreur');
 }
}
```

the sql function:

```
 public function duplicate() {
     try{
    $c = base::getConnection();
    $query=$c->prepare ("INSERT INTO outillage(num_serie,id_art,article,id_doc,document,ilot,emplacement,liste_tubes) SELECT (:num_serie,:id_art,:article,:id_doc,:document,:ilot,:emplacement,:liste_tubes WHERE id=:id);");
    $query->bindParam(':id',$this->id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindParam(':id_art',$this->id_art,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindParam(':num_serie',$this->num_serie,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':article',$this->article,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':id_doc',$this->id_doc,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':document',$this->document,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':ilot',$this->ilot,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->bindParam(':emplacement',$this->emplacement,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->bindParam(':liste_tubes',$this->liste_tubes,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->execute();
 }
 catch (Exception $e){
     echo $e->getMessage();
 }
```

}

and my html button to copy :

```
<form method="post" action="Site.php?a=duplicateOutil" onsubmit="">
                            <button type="button"  class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Non</button>
                            <input name="id" type="hidden" type="text" value="'.$l->__get("id").'">
                            <input id="confirmer" type="submit" value="Oui" class=btn btn-primary">
                        </form>
```

Comment: your syntax for INSERT query is wrong

Comment: I can see typos `class=btn btn-primary"`! Wrong use of a prepared_statement `SELECT (:num_serie`!  This seems also wrong `value="'.$l->__get("id").'"`.   Heavy to help here.

Comment: Also the part where `duplicate()` is called is missing here. There is only `insert()`

Comment: what is wrong you think ? , i used isset to see if my var is define .

Comment: You need to start from scratch.  Your use of prepared statements is wrong.

Comment: i will learn more abour prepared statement to understand why my syntaxe is wrong